# When does this integral converge $\int_{0^+}^{1}{\frac{x^a\ln(x^b)}{e^x-1}}dx$?

Tags: convergence-divergence

$$ \int_{0^+}^{1}{\frac{x^a\ln(x^b)}{e^x-1}}dx,\quad \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R},a\ge 1
$$

It's from a final exam. I just can't find a proper function to prove convergence or divergence.

For $b=0 \rightarrow \frac{x^a\ln(x^b)}{e^x-1}=0 \therefore$ the integral converges.

I know that $ \int_{0^+}^{1}{x^a\ln(x^b)}dx$ converges (although not useful for LCT).

Assuming that $\int_{0^+}^{1}{\frac{\ln(x)}{e^x-1}}dx$ converges:

For $b\lt0 \rightarrow \ln(x^b)\gt0\therefore$ I can use LCT. Is correct to say that if $b\gt0$ I can multiply everything by $-1$ and say that convergence is also valid in this case? Then I can take $b$ out of the integral and check with LCT:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}{\frac{\frac{x^a\ln(x)}{e^x-1}}{\frac{\ln(x)}{e^x-1}}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}{x^a}=0$$

Yet again I say that if $\int_{0^+}^{1}{\frac{\ln(x)}{e^x-1}}dx$ converges then $-\int_{0^+}^{1}{\frac{\ln(1/x)}{e^x-1}}dx$ also converges. Now I can use LCT again, but got stuck proving this. I thought about using DCT for $\int_{0^+}^{1}{\frac{\ln(1/x)}{e^x-1}}dx\le\int_{0^+}^{1}{\frac{1/x}{e^x-1}}dx\le\int_{0^+}^{1}{\frac{1}{e^x-1}}dx$, but again couldn't prove convergence on anyone.

Can you guide me on which way to take?

Comment: Just to be clear, this is from an *old* final exam that you're using to study, right?

Comment: Hahaha, of course. My real final is in a month. This one is 5 years old.

Comment: Why don't you use $\ln(x^b)=b\ln x$ to get rid of the $b$? It does not play any role in the problem.

Comment: I did took out b (when I said "I can take b out of the integral"). But for using LCT the integrand must be always positive, right?. That's where b plays a role (I think).

Comment: I mean do it at the very beginning and do not talk about it at all. Btw, "proof" is the noun and "prove" is the verb. I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, english is my second language.

Comment: Obviously the convergence problem is at $x=0$, and $$
\frac{{x^a \ln (x^b )}}{{e^x  - 1}} = b\frac{x}{{e^x  - 1}}x^{a - 1} \ln x \sim bx^{a - 1} \ln x
$$ as $x\to 0+$. This will show you that the requirement is $a>0$.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see what comes out of that and get back to you.

Comment: Oh, it is given that $a\geq 1$. Then it is even easier: $$
\left| {\frac{{x^a \ln (x^b )}}{{e^x  - 1}}} \right| = \left| b \right|\frac{x}{{e^x  - 1}}x^{a - 1} \left| {\ln x} \right| \le \left| b \right|x^{a - 1} \left| {\ln x} \right| \le \left| b \right|\left| {\ln x} \right|
$$ for $0<x<1$.

Comment: This works!. Thanks Gary. Please post it, so I can upvote it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

If $a\geq 1$ and $b\in \mathbb R$, then
\begin{align*}
\left| {\int_0^1 {\frac{{x^a \ln (x^b )}}{{e^x  - 1}}dx} } \right| &= \int_0^1 { \frac{{x^a \left| {\ln (x^b )} \right|}}{{e^x  - 1}}dx}  = \left| b \right|\int_0^1 {\frac{x}{{e^x  - 1}}x^{a - 1} \left| {\ln x} \right|dx} \\ & \le \left| b \right|\int_0^1 {\left| {\ln x} \right|dx}  = \left| b \right|.
\end{align*}